# Creating a percent calculator

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to create a calculator that gives me the percent of a person's income. I am new to JavaScript and jQuery.

This gives

> Uncaught ReferenceError: calculate is not defined
>   Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token

```
function calculate();
{   

      var annual_Income = jQuery('#a1').val();
      var income_Pledged = (jQuery('#a2').val()/100;
      var x = annual_Income * income_Pledged;
      var weekly = Math.floor(x/52);
      var monthly = Math.floor(x/12);
      var quarterly = Math.floor(x/4);   
      var annual_total = weekly + monthly + quarterly;
      var htmlstr = '<div> <p>Annual Household Income: $ ' + annual_Income + '</p><p>Weekly Pledge: $ '  + weekly + '</p><p>Monthly Pledge: $ '  + monthly +
                   '</p><p>Quaterly Pledge: $ '  + quarterly + ' </p><p>Annual Pledge: $ '  + annual_total + '</p>';

      //alert(x);
      jQuery( "div.result-container" ).html( htmlstr ); 


}
```

Comment: And what is the expected and actual output? Errors in console?

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: calculate is not defined

Comment: Edit your question and include it

Comment: missing a closing bracket: var income_Pledged = (jQuery('#a2').val()/100;

Comment: and Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ;

Comment: Well there is a syntax error. Of course it will not run. Click on the error in the console and it will take you to the line with the syntax error or use an editor with syntax error checking.

Comment: like i said im so new to this..... Ill review it

Comment: Thank you all for the input

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remove the semi-colon from the first line:

```
function calculate();
```

Also you have unbalanced brackets on the following line:

```
var income_Pledged = (jQuery('#a2').val()/100;
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!! Works.... Have to pay attention to everything